# html accessing variable value from c# codebehind

Tags: c#, javascript, query-string, code-behind

I'm trying to access a value from the code behind to create a query string. This is the simplest way I thought of, but if you guys have any recommendations please feel free to give your thoughts:

I have this link that would generate the querystring and would trigger a lightbox to show the page in front of the main page:

```
<a id="link" runat="server" href="thepage.aspx?id=<%strtest%>">Show the page with strtest</a>
```

Code behind:

```
public string strtest = "";
:
string strTestID = Request.QueryString["ID"].ToString();
:
strtest = strTestID ;
```

At the moment, it would just give me a blank lightbox. If I take out the lightbox and see the url generated, the url looks like this.

```
thepage.aspx?id=<%strtest%>
```

So like I said, I did the simplest way I can think of.  I also thought of implementing javascript with this

```
string jsString= "changeLink('" + strtest  + "');";
```

But that would give me an error with my parameters which btw is weird as it works without it.

So yeah, any help is appreciated.

Comment: From what I can see strtest should be there but it's not being print out by using <%= strtest %>. Other than that I can't see what the problem might be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are seeing this behavior because of the 'runat="server"' attribute on the anchor tag. Remove the attribute and the value will be displayed correctly. Also, you will want to change the code from <%strtest%> to <%= strtest%>

Answer (score 2):

I think you want:

```
<a id="link" href="thepage.aspx?id=<%=strtest%>">Show the page with strtest</a>
```

In asp.net 4, this is preferable:

```
<a id="link" href="thepage.aspx?id=<%:strtest%>">Show the page with strtest</a>
```

This form does automatic encoding to help prevent XSS and other attacks.

Comment: do you think doing this kind of query string passing is safe?

Comment: I'm not a security expert, but it depends a lot on where `strtest` comes from.  If it comes from user input or form values, where it could be maliciously crafted, then it can definitely be a problem.  The new `<%: %>` syntax definitely helps mitigate that risk though.

Comment: there is always a possibility for hackers to inject your code, specially with querystring cause everyone can see the page needs some kind of ID. Suggestion: always check the ID from the querystring whether the ID is a valid ID.